# PHPunit single ok/failed result

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to run a set of PHPUnits and have their results "centralized" as simple "ok" or "failed".

Right now it seems that PHPUnits renders long list of things - which is good while developing or testing things by hand but as I want to integrate PhPunit with other tools and I need a simple "ok"/"failed" response.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you run the PHPUnit from command-line, then the script returns `0` to shell if all test is correct but other value if there is any error.
You can use some similar:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml > /dev/null && echo ok || echo failed
```

`> /dev/null` - forward the phpunit output to /dev/null - not interested for me
`&& echo ok` - print `ok` to the standard output when all test correct
`|| echo failed` - print `failed` to the standard output when any test is failed

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `ResultPrinter` class that extends `PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter` and make it print whatever you need and nothing more. Then in your `phpunit.xml` file you point at it with `<phpunit>` tag's  `printerClass` attribute.

[Here](https://github.com/clagiordano/phpunit-result-printer/blob/master/src/ResultPrinter.php) is a nice simple example of how such a printer might class look like.

BTW, if you're looking for a tool that integrates more tools, like phpunit, phpstan, phpcs, etc. and runs them all with a single command, you might wanna take a look at [GrumPHP](https://github.com/phpro/grumphp).